# ClaimRow in a For loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, loop

I want to give out more than one code in an email based on a number field in a DE.

Currently, I'm using a for loop that goes from 1 to that number field, I have the claimrow within the loop, but for it shows me the same coupon code multiple times in the same email.
The for loop runs successfully.

Here is what I use for testing now.

```
%%[ 

for @i = 1 to @nr_of_combos DO

    VAR @CouponRow
    SET @CouponRow = ClaimRow('Coupons_active', IsClaimed','Salesforce_Subscriber_Key',Salesforce_Subscriber_Key)

    IF EMPTY(@CouponRow) THEN 
    ]%%

    <p>No coupons available… please contact us … </p>

    %%[ ELSE ]%% 

        %%=FIELD(@CouponRow,'CouponCode')=%% 

    %%[ ENDIF ]%%

%%[ 

NEXT @i 

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured it out.
I have created a new field in the DE that represents the NR of coupon code allocated to a person. So if you have 2 or more codes in an email, all entries will be unique. I just named it 'i' for my test.

```
SET @CouponRow = ClaimRow('Coupons_active', 'IsClaimed','Salesforce_Subscriber_Key',Salesforce_Subscriber_Key,'EmailAddress',Emailaddress, 'i', @i)
```